# How can I setup Javascript dynamically to expand divs when clicking another div?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, html

I am creating a main menu in asp.net using dynamically created divs.

The divs are associated with 3 different levels.

I have done everything I need but am struggling with expanding and collapsing the menus.

I need to show only level 1 items when the page is loaded (probably easier using CSS?)

Then I need to be able to expand level2 items for a particular level1 item when that item is clicked.

I will then need to collapse them after a certain time period.

The code below shows how the divs are created and statements for specific levels:

```
  private void CreateDiv(string divId, string URL, int level)
    {
        //Attributes for all items
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.Attributes.Add("id", divId);

        div.Controls.Add(
            new Label()
            {
                ID = "lbl" + divId,
                Text = divId
            });


        if (level == 1)
        {

            div.Attributes.Add("class", "level1");
            //Code to expand level 2 items

        }

        if (level == 2)
        {
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "level2");
            //Code to expand level 3 items
        }
        if (level == 3) //Specific attributes for level 3 items
        {
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "level3");
            div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + URL + "', 'mywindow');");
        }
        divMenuleft.Controls.Add(div);

    }
```

Comment: Why not use some css in there?

Comment: There are many examples online... search for a 'slider', you should find the CSS for sliding menu items (expanding)
I like to use the old #divX trick myself... you write css for the page like so:

Comment: Yes I have seen them but I would would need to have a different class for each parent menu ID to make sure that only the correct child elements are expanded. Well that's I imagine it anyway.

Comment: You could just use an array to create the id's

(note this code only has one element expanded at any time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this myself in the end like so:

private void CreateDiv(string divId, string URL, int level, string parentid, string MenuId)
{
    //Attributes for all items
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.Attributes.Add("id", divId);

```
div.Controls.Add(
    new Label()
    {
        ID = "lbl" + divId,
        Text = divId
    });


if (level == 1)
{

    div.Attributes.Add("class", "level1");
    //Code to expand level 2 items
    div.Attributes.Add("onclick","expand('p" + MenuId + "');");
}

if (level == 2)
{
    div.Attributes.Add("class", "level2 " + "p" + parentid);
    //Code to expand level 3 items
    div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:expand('p" + MenuId + "')");
}
if (level == 3) //Specific attributes for level 3 items
{
    div.Attributes.Add("class", "level3 " + "p" + parentid);
    div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + URL + "', 'mywindow');");

}
divMenuleft.Controls.Add(div);
```

}

```
            function expand(divref) {
                $("." + divref + "").show();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("." + divref + "").hide();

                }, 15000);

            }



            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".level2").hide();
                $(".level3").hide();

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
#content > div {
display: none;
}

#content > div:target {
display: block;
}</style>
```

**HTML:** (list Item Link)

```
<ol>
<li>
    <a href="#div1">Menu Item MAIN</a></li>
</ol>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
    <a>
        Menu Item CHILD</a> </div>
```

Comment: That's a very basic generic way of showing list items, unfortunately it has nothing to do with the setup I posted above. I managed to solve the issue on my own in the end but thanks for the help.